# Does it matter if my companion dies?

Tags: the-outer-worlds

My companion loves to go running headlong into a fight, even when I'm sniping from a distance, instead of waiting for the enemy to come  to us. When she does this she tends to get herself killed. She always gets right back up again the fight, so it seems like companion death is meaningless, but I'm wondering if there's some consequences to my companion dying that I'm just not yet aware of.

Are there any consequences to companion dying, or are they effectively immortal?

Comment: Make sure to set your preferences in the Companions menu. The right-most icon in the menu where you can equip them or change their perks allows you to set preferences like Melee/Ranged, Aggressive/Defensive etc. Nevertheless, they do seem a bit suicidal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no consequences for companion death on any difficulty but Supernova. If they die on supernova difficulty they stay dead.

Which will happen almost instantly as they die really quickly in my opnion.